# Limit User Linux Login using IPTABLES

Tags: iptables

Is posible to limit user login using iptables?
It's like if one user is logged in, no one else can log in using that user.

I try this command:

> iptables  -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 22 -m connlimit
>   --connlimit-above 1 -j REJECT

It can limit user login, but just for 1 IP. I still can login using another PC with different IP Address.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Iptables has no way to tell if two different ssh connections come from the same user or from different users. Look at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127077/number-of-ssh-connections-on-a-single-linux-machine) in unix.stackexchange.com for the correct way to restrict multiple ssh logins from the same user, using sshd configuration rather than iptables.